# Не понимаю как сделать реализацию поставки оценки в blazor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, blazor

Есть переменная типа int в каком-то классе, и при нажатии на кнопку эта переменная увеличивается на 1 (типу увеличения оценки как в stackoverflow), надо что бы это мог сделать только Аутифицированый пользователь (использую AuthenticationStateProvider) и мог поставить только один раз (что бы не накручивали), но я вообще не понимаю как мне это сделать без заношение всех поставленных оценок в БД

Comment: Никак, и самое главное - зачем? Можете конечно в файле хранить данные, но смысл в этом какой? Да и не совсем тривиальная задача - синхронизация доступа к файлу.

Comment: Ну вот у меня есть сайт с чем-то и у него есть оценка в виде числа, как у stackoverflow, я хочу реализовать что-то подобное